# How to include a Mapbox Studio Tileset in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, mapbox-studio, pbf

I would like to include in my Leaflet map a vector tile set that I uploaded to Mapbox Studio. I first uploaded a tileset to the tiles page of Mapbox studio. Then I created a new style and added my tile set to this style. I would like to include the vector tile set in my Leaflet map by referencing the protobuf file URL with VectorGrid. Like this...

```
L.vectorGrid
  .protobuf(
    <the protobuf URL>,
    getTileOptions....
  )
```

I believe this is the correct URL. https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/gideongrossman2/ck9i7cvp32an61ik0p8ciublg/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk..xxxxxxxxxxx-jw4dvQ However, when I go to this page. For example, substituting 7/32/38 for {z}/{x}/{y}, to see part of Illinois, the screen is black. I think I might have created a style and am in fact looking at it, however it appears I have made the style completely black. All I need to import into my Leaflet map is the outlines of zip codes. What is the simplest way to create a tile set that I can import into a Leaflet map that just includes the zip code boundaries? I started with a shapefile from the US Census Bureau's shapefiles repository.